# Linux file permissions outside home

Tags: linux, permissions

I want to create files and directories in a directory outside my home directory (on a different physical drive as I'm running out of space on my main drive). However I'm getting files with different permissions when I create them in a directory outside home which causes permission denied errors when I later execute some commands on these files I created.

I would like to use the directory outside my home (which is on different drive) in the same way as my home directory. How to do it?

To be specific, I'm following this manual http://project-magpie.github.io/yocto/2014/09/26/building-a-yocto-image-for-the-a20-olinuxino-lime/ but when executing "source oe-init-build-env ../build/a20-lime" command I'm getting permission denied error when I work in a directory outside my home on different drive.

When I work in my home I get no permission denied errors.

Comment: I think you will have to provide more information on how you have set up your new directory on the other drive, how its file permissions look in comparison with your home directory, what exact error message you are facing, etc. Otherwise it will be difficult for others to help.

Comment: Please add output of: `mount` command, `echo $SHELL` and output of `source oe-init-build-env ../build/a20-lime`.